# jquery invert class attribute on click

Tags: jquery, click, addclass, removeclass

With this simple markup:

```
<a id="foo" class="first" href="#"></a>
```

I wish to obtain something like this:

```
$('#foo').click (function () { 
    if $('foo').hasClass('first') { $('foo').removeClass('first').addClass('second');

    if $('foo').hasClass('second') { $('foo').removeClass('second').addClass('first'); 
});
```

I don't know before which class has the element, if "first" or "second". 
How is it possible to do this every time I click on the element, refreshing the reading of the class?

I wish I was clear.

Any help would be apreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to note: to select `<a id="foo">` you must use `$('#foo')`.  You are using `$('foo')` which selects `<foo>` elements (and is obviously not what you want).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to use `toggleClass()` to toggle more than one class at a time is to pass multiple classes to it at the same time like this:

```
$('#foo').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('first second');
});
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/HWkWC/

Note: you can pass more than one class to `toggleClass()` (separated by a space) and it will toggle each class independently rather than making multiple calls to `toggleClass()`.  This is all described in the [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) for toggleClass.

Comment: @dotNETbeginner - the comment you removed was true when written.  Look at the edits of the previous answer (which were done without any comment) to see.  The main reason I wrote my answer was because the other answer was so wrong and didn't take advantage of how `toggleClass()` can take multiple class names.

Comment: thanks for this answer, it works perfectly. I vote for this answer. You can vote for my question if you want. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

```
$('#foo').click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('first').toggleClass('second');
}
```

Comment: +1 but make sure to update your selector from `$('foo')` to `$('#foo')`

Comment: You will need to know what classes to toggle, otherwise i don't see much chance in doing so ;)

Comment: Thanks naomik, but it's not what I need.

Comment: @bobighorus why don't you go and read the api for toggleClass because this answer does what you want unless you have expressed yourself incorrectly.

Comment: I can't believe this answer got three votes.  `toggleClass` may be the right idea, but this code has several errors in it and won't even compile, much less run.